# Django ORM Annotations: Most common group of user queryset

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a QuerySet of the auth.User model.

I want to know: Which groups are the ones which contain the most of these users.

Example: I have three groups, with these users:

- g1: u1 u2 u3 u4
- g2: u1 u2
- g3: u1 u4 u5 u6
- g4: u5 u6 u7

User-QuerySet: u1 u2 u3

Result (counting the members which are in the given User-Queryset):

- g1: count 3
- g2: count 2
- g3: count 1
- g4: count 0

How can I get an annotated QuerySet of the model Group this with Django 1.8?

**Use Case**

Show how many members with "x" in the user name each group has.

**SQL**

```
SELECT auth_group.id, auth_group.name, 
 (SELECT COUNT(auth_user_groups.id) FROM auth_user_groups WHERE
    auth_user_groups.group_id = auth_group.id AND
    auth_user_groups.user_id IN (SELECT auth_user.id FROM auth_user WHERE username LIKE '%x%')) AS user_cnt 
FROM auth_group ORDER BY user_cnt DESC;
```

**Update**

Group `g4` has no matching members, but it should be in the annotated QuerySet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from django.db.expressions import Case, When
from django.db.models import Count, IntegerField

Group.objects.annotate(
    user_cnt=Count(Case(When(user__in=user_list, then=1),
                        output_field=IntegerField())),
)
```

Comment: Nice, your answer works. The resulting SQL: `SELECT "auth_group"."id", "auth_group"."name", COUNT(CASE WHEN "auth_user_groups"."user_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "auth_user" U0 WHERE U0."username"::text LIKE testfoobar%) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "user_cnt" FROM "auth_group" LEFT OUTER JOIN "auth_user_groups" ON ( "auth_group"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."group_id" ) GROUP BY "auth_group"."id", "auth_group"."name" ORDER BY "user_cnt" DESC`

Answer (score 1):

```
list_group = []
for grp in Group.objects.filter(id__in = [g1, g2, g3, g4]):
    print grp, '---', User.objects.filter(id__in = [u1, u2, u3], groups = grp).count()
    list_group([grp, User.objects.filter(id__in = [u1, u2, u3], groups = grp).count()])
```

Hope this answer is acceptable..

Comment: Yes, this works, but I prefer loops in SQL to loops in python. "How can I get an annotated QuerySet of the model Group this with Django 1.8?"

Answer (score 0):

In Django we can group the some object based on the `values` and we can apply the `annotation` on the grouping result.
Read this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) it will explain how to use the values and annotation.

```
group =  Group.objects.filter(id=XX).values("user").annotate(Count("user__pk"))
```

If you need to only the users under the group means:

```
group = Group.objects.annotate(Count("user__pk"))
```

Comment: The result should be an annotated queryset of group instances. The input is a queryset of user instances. I can't see this in your example.